# How to get a list of all Microsoft Media Foundation Transforms (MFTs) available on a system

Tags: visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

I'm a newbie to native development on Windows, but I've been tasked with creating a small app that will list out all the transformers for various video+audio codecs.

Looking at the MSDN documentation, there doesn't seem to be much direct documentation on doing this.  Docs that I've found indicate that this information is stored in the registry (not sure where) so that could be a vector.

1. Is this possible?
2. Generally how should I do it?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

It does seem that a call to  MFTEnumEx with the parameters of type MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO set to NULL returns a count of 8

```
MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_DECODER,MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL,NULL, NULL, &ppActivate, &count);
assert(count > 0);
```

Still have to get the actual values though.  But the passed ppActivate param should contain an enumeration of them.

**EDIT:**
It's surprising, but while the count above == 8, there are no video or audio attributes(the video/audio IMFAttributes object is NULL)

```
 IMFAttributes* videoAttributes = NULL;    
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            hr = pProfile->GetVideoAttributes(&videoAttributes);
            //If there are no container attributes set in the transcode profile, the GetVideoAttributes method succeeds and videoAttributes receives NULL.

        }
assert(videoAttributes != NULL);  //FAILS!
```

**EDIT:**

This is a method that pulls all the IMFMediaTypes from the machine(modified call from the book [Developing Microsoft® Media Foundation Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005WZ0SJ6)); I then enumerate over them in the caller:

```
HRESULT CTranscoder::GetVideoOutputAvailableTypes(
    DWORD flags, 
    CComPtr<IMFCollection>& pTypeCollection)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFActivate** pActivateArray = NULL;
    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO outputType;
    UINT32 nMftsFound = 0;

    do
    {
        // create the collection in which we will return the types found
        hr = MFCreateCollection(&pTypeCollection);
        BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr);

        // initialize the structure that describes the output streams that the encoders must
        // be able to produce.  In this case we want video encoders - so major type is video, 
        // and we want the specified subtype
        outputType.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
        outputType.guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_WMV3;

        // get a collection of MFTs that fit the requested pattern - video encoders,
        // with the specified subtype, and using the specified search flags
        hr = MFTEnumEx(
            MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER,         // type of object to find - video encoders
            flags,                              // search flags
            NULL,                               // match all input types for an encoder
            &outputType,                        // get encoders with specified output type
            &pActivateArray,
            &nMftsFound);
        BREAK_ON_FAIL(hr);

        // now that we have an array of activation objects for matching MFTs, loop through 
        // each of those MFTs, extracting all possible and available formats from each of them
        for(UINT32 x = 0; x < nMftsFound; x++)
        {
            CComPtr<IMFTransform> pEncoder;
            UINT32 typeIndex = 0;

            // activate the encoder that corresponds to the activation object
            hr = pActivateArray[x]->ActivateObject(IID_IMFTransform, 
                (void**)&pEncoder);

            // while we don't have a failure, get each available output type for the MFT 
            // encoder we keep looping until there are no more available types.  If there 
            // are no more types for the encoder, IMFTransform::GetOutputAvailableTypes[] 
            // will return MF_E_NO_MORE_TYPES
            while(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IMFMediaType* pType;

                // get the avilable type for the type index, and increment the typeIndex 
                // counter
                hr = pEncoder->GetOutputAvailableType(0, typeIndex++, &pType);
                if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // store the type in the IMFCollection
                    hr = pTypeCollection->AddElement(pType);
                }
            }
        }
    } while(false);

    // possible valid errors that may be returned after the previous for loop is done
    if(hr == MF_E_NO_MORE_TYPES  ||  hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_TYPE_NOT_SET)
        hr = S_OK;

    // if we successfully used MFTEnumEx() to allocate an array of the MFT activation 
    // objects, then it is our responsibility to release each one and free up the memory 
    // used by the array
    if(pActivateArray != NULL)
    {
        // release the individual activation objects
        for(UINT32 x = 0; x < nMftsFound; x++)
        {
            if(pActivateArray[x] != NULL)
                pActivateArray[x]->Release();
        }

        // free the memory used by the array
        CoTaskMemFree(pActivateArray);
        pActivateArray = NULL;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Caller:

```
    hr=transcoder.GetVideoOutputAvailableTypes( MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL, availableTypes);
    if (FAILED(hr)){
        wprintf_s(L"didn't like the printVideoProfiles method");
    }

    DWORD availableInputTypeCount =0;
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr= availableTypes->GetElementCount(&availableInputTypeCount);
    }
    for(DWORD i = 0; i< availableInputTypeCount  && SUCCEEDED(hr); i++)
    {

        //really a IMFMediaType*
        IMFAttributes* mediaInterface = NULL;
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                hr = availableTypes->GetElement(i, (IUnknown**)&mediaInterface) ;}

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){ 
                //see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376629(v=VS.85).aspx for a list of attributes to pull off the media interface.

                GUID majorType;
                hr = mediaInterface->GetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, &majorType);
                LPOLESTR majorGuidString = NULL;
                hr = StringFromCLSID(majorType,&majorGuidString);
                wprintf_s(L"major type: %s \n", majorGuidString);
                wprintf_s(L"is a video? %i \n", IsEqualGUID(MFMediaType_Video,majorType));

                GUID subType;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &subType))){
                    LPOLESTR minorGuidString = NULL;
                    if(SUCCEEDED(StringFromCLSID(subType,&minorGuidString)))
                        wprintf_s(L"subtype: %s \n", minorGuidString);
                }

                //Contains a DirectShow format GUID for a media type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373477(v=VS.85).aspx
                GUID formatType;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetGUID(MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE, &formatType))){
                    LPOLESTR formatTypeString = NULL;
                    if(SUCCEEDED(StringFromCLSID(formatType,&formatTypeString)))
                        wprintf_s(L"format type: %s \n", formatTypeString);
                }

                UINT32 numeratorFrameRate = 0;
                UINT32 denominatorFrameRate = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(MFGetAttributeRatio(mediaInterface, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, &numeratorFrameRate, &denominatorFrameRate)))
                    wprintf_s(L"framerate: %i/%i \n", numeratorFrameRate, denominatorFrameRate);

                UINT32 widthOfFrame = 0;
                UINT32 heightOfFrame = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(MFGetAttributeSize(mediaInterface, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &widthOfFrame, &heightOfFrame)))
                    wprintf_s(L"height of frame: %i width of frame: %i \n", heightOfFrame, widthOfFrame);

                UINT32 isCompressedP = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_COMPRESSED, &isCompressedP)))
                    wprintf_s(L"is media compressed? %iu \n", (BOOL)isCompressedP);

                BOOL isCompressedP2 = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED((((IMFMediaType*)mediaInterface)->IsCompressedFormat(&isCompressedP2))))
                    wprintf_s(L"is media compressed2? %i \n", isCompressedP2);

                UINT32 fixedSampleSizeP = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES, &fixedSampleSizeP)))
                    wprintf_s(L"is fixed sample size? %iu \n", fixedSampleSizeP);

                UINT32 sampleSize = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE, &sampleSize)))
                    wprintf_s(L"sample size: %iu \n", sampleSize);

                UINT32 averateBitrate = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, &averateBitrate)))
                    wprintf_s(L"average bitrate: %iu \n", averateBitrate);

                UINT32 aspectRatio = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_PAD_CONTROL_FLAGS, &aspectRatio)))
                    wprintf_s(L"4 by 3? %i  16 by 9? %i None? %i \n", aspectRatio == MFVideoPadFlag_PAD_TO_4x3, MFVideoPadFlag_PAD_TO_16x9 == aspectRatio, MFVideoPadFlag_PAD_TO_None == aspectRatio);

                UINT32 drmFlag = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_DRM_FLAGS, &drmFlag)))
                    wprintf_s(L"requires digital drm: %i requires analog drm: %i  requires no drm: %i", drmFlag == MFVideoDRMFlag_DigitallyProtected, drmFlag == MFVideoDRMFlag_AnalogProtected, MFVideoDRMFlag_None == drmFlag);

                UINT32 panScanEnabled = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_PAN_SCAN_ENABLED, &panScanEnabled)))
                    wprintf_s(L"pan/scan enabled? %i", panScanEnabled);

                UINT32 maxFrameRateNumerator = 0;
                UINT32 maxFrameRateDenominator = 0;
                if(SUCCEEDED(MFGetAttributeRatio(mediaInterface, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, &maxFrameRateNumerator, &maxFrameRateDenominator)))
                    wprintf_s(L"max framerate range: %i/%i \n", maxFrameRateNumerator, maxFrameRateDenominator);

            }

    }
```

It's getting some attributes from the IMFMediaInterface, but not many attributes are set and 
 the call to `mediaInterface->GetUINT32(MF_MT_COMPRESSED, &isCompressedP)` isn't successful but the call to `(IMFMediaType*)mediaInterface)->IsCompressedFormat(&isCompressedP2)` is, which makes me wonder if I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but noone should go away unanswered.

As you discovered, `MFTEnumEx` can give you the list of `MFTs`, either bulk list, or filtered with a criteria. Now once you have the collection of transforms, you have `IMFActivate` for every transform available.

Having `IMFActivate` on hands, see [this code snippet](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/MediaFoundation/EnumerateTransforms/EnumerateTransforms.cpp#L136) how you can obtain information about this transform: you list attributes or access attribute of interest using its key, you can obtain the category, input and output media types (`MFT_INPUT_TYPES_Attributes`, `MFT_OUTPUT_TYPES_Attributes`).

Here is sample code and MFT dump samples:

- [How to enumerate Media Foundation transforms on your system](https://matthewvaneerde.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/how-to-enumerate-media-foundation-transforms-on-your-system/)
- [Enumerating Media Foundation Transforms (MFTs)](http://alax.info/blog/1375)

Comment: I think a copy of the first sample code link (the one pointing to an MSDN DevBlogs page) can be found here:

https://matthewvaneerde.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/how-to-enumerate-media-foundation-transforms-on-your-system/

(Original link isn't working for me. Don't know if it's a temporary issue but Microsoft are generally incapable of keeping a URL working longer than a few weeks so it's no surprise.)

Comment: I fixed the link. In MS's defense, it was not weeks but 10+ years since the answer was written. During this time a lot of things happened, including [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11809455/matthew-van-eerde) of that article behind the link coming to StackOverflow to post some answers and stopping doing this.

Comment: They've broken every link going to everything on MSDN Blogs so many times over the years that they don't deserve the defense. :) You can almost guarantee any link to a MSDN URL on here older than 3 years is broken. It's incredibly frustrating. My personal website is better run, which is ridiculous.