# MediaFoundation, bitmap array to mp4

Tags: c++, video, bitmap, mp4, ms-media-foundation

I hold bitmaps as BYTE arrays which holds RGB values of each pixel in a very similar and interchangeable format with microsoft's CBitmap class. So lets consider I have an array of CBitmaps and I want to convert them to mp4 with MediaFoundation Transcode Api as in this example: [toMp4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476(v=vs.85).aspx) . However in this example, they stream from an url.

```
 // Use the source resolver to create the media source
  hr = pResolver->CreateObjectFromURL(pszURL, MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE, NULL, &ObjectType, &pSource);
```

In my case I have my bitmaps in the memory. So I believe I can use this function instead. [IMFSourceResolver::CreateObjectFromByteStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704671(v=vs.85).aspx)

I am not sure if this is doable in this way. As a summary how can I convert my CBitmap arrays to mp4 with transcode api ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transcoding API assumes that you have source and destination for the operation in certain "format" recognized by Media Foundation. That is, source and destination are both represented by Media Foundation sources and sinks, and then the API covers the process of converting one to another.

It is not the case of yours. Your source is not Media Foundation friendly.

For you scenario the appropriate API is [Sink Writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819461). It offers a friendly interface to push non Media Foundation data into Media Foundation pipeline, and produces encoded video file by means of Media Foundation.

That is, you get bitmap bits from your images, you configure Sink Writer instance to accept such input format and then it takes care of the encoding.

See [Tutorial: Using the Sink Writer to Encode Video](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477) for respective sample code and guidance through the process.

Comment: The linked example seems to fail at SetInputMediaType(...) if I change the sub type to MFVideoFormat_MP4V.

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you going to transcode from `MFVideoFormat_MP4V` to H.264/MP4?

Comment: No, I'd also like to encode a sequence of raster images into an MP4 file as the gentlemen above.
I tried to take the tutorial example and change the encoder subtype from MFVideoFormat_WMV3 to MFVideoFormat_MP4V.

When doing that I get the following error when calling SetInputMediaType(...) on the IMFSinkWriter.

"0xc00d5212 : No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content."

Comment: OK, that's what I originally thought of. So Windows Media Foundation just does not have `MFVideoFormat_MP4V` encoder in it and hence the error. You actually need `MFVideoFormat_H264` in the media type, and `.mp4` in target file extension would be resolved internally into MP4 format that you request.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to get me over the hump. How do you know all this stuff about Media Foundation? The documentation out there doesn't seem to be so hot.

Comment: Well it helps me to imagine how I would go about developing this stuff myself if I had to. Quite so many things in Media Foundation are developed with care and attention, even though it does not look like this at a first sight. As for documentation, it could definitely be better (as well as samples and release/update notes, and backward compatibility, and codec/format coverage and other).

Comment: One small follow up though, do you know how I could programmatically fetch all the available codecs through Media Foundation?

Comment: @AlonGranot: [How to get a list of all Microsoft Media Foundation Transforms (MFTs) available on a system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853931/868014)