# MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE on calling MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL

Tags: winapi, mp3, ms-media-foundation

I’m developing an mp3 decoder using Media Foundation API.

Everything works fine in my pc and on all the computers I’ve tested, except for a PC with Windows 7 Home Premium, where the api

```
IMFSourceReader * pReader = NULL;
HRESULT hrError = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(<file_to_decode.mp3>, 0, &pReader);
```

fails with error MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE.

The mp3 file is the same for all tests.

Am I missing something? Any idea?

Comment: MP3 codec missing / broken / sulking on that machine? [possibly helpful link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/codec-tweak-tool)

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853931/1466421) to see what Media foundation transforms are on your system.